# Is it possible to create an web app without use of android studio?

Tags: android, web

I want to make an web layout android app without the use of android studio as My laptop is not supporting android studio. Can you help me to create one web android app [For this link](http://doopme.co.in/recharge/b2b/app/login.php)

Or can you give me the solution of how to do so without the use of android studio. May be online and i can download it.

Comment: Yes. You can create an app without using Android studio but I am curious as to why you laptop is not supporting Android Studio.

Comment: may i know how??

Comment: You can use your text editor and run gradle your terminal. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html

Comment: Android studio basically runs a gradle script to compile resources, source files and build your apk.

Comment: i am new to android development anything which i can understand

Comment: Like I said earlier. It's easier to try and fix your Android Studio than to run from the terminal. Especially if you 're new to Android

Comment: my laptop have very less  memory to install AS

Comment: I found this https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#low_memory, I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use eclipse instead of android studio

[Eclipse for Android Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-android-developers/neonm6)

Comment: currently i don't have it!!  and i have to deliver now

Comment: Sublime text with Gradle and android SDK. If you think you can handle this feat.

Comment: P S I dont know anything about android app development

Comment: @user2018030 do not use Eclipse. Eclipse support has ended long time ago. Use Android Studio which is supported by Google officially.

Comment: Problem is i am not able to use any of the software. can i do it online